# Format USB pen Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb, formatting

I'm a new ubuntu user (loving it), but I have a little problem right now.

I have a USB Pen that needs formatting.

What's the best GUI driven USB formater for Linux?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Maybe GParted?  http://www.ehow.com/how_4963426_format-usb-flash-drive-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnome Format is pretty good, Gparted too but it takes a little too long to start and if you want to use it regulary, it gets annoying.
Gnome format is in the repositories since 9.04 i believe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of Gparted, which has been in the repositories for as long as I can remember. You can run it from the Administration menu after you install with this command:

> sudo apt-get install gparted

If you're dealing with larger media, Gparted does take a while to scan all discs. To go around this, start up a terminal and type in:

> gksudo gparted /dev/sdx

where sdx is the pendrive you want to format. This will have gparted scan only the disc you want to format, and speeds it up quite a bit. gksudo works better than sudo when launcher graphical applications.

Answer (score 0):

The preinstalled Ubuntu Disk Utility seems friendly enough and provides other useful options (ejection) for flash drives. It's located under System -> Administration -> Disk Utility.